# drawRect:rect how to call this method , I am using to draw a string

Tags: iphone

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    CGContextRef  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 24, kCGEncodingFontSpecific);
    CGContextSetTextPosition(context,80,80);
    CGContextShowText(context, "hello", 6);
    //not even this works
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 1,1, "hello", 6);
}
```

I want to know how to call the above method, I have pasted the above code into the implementation file, but don't know why it's not called when I execute the project.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setNeedsDisplay should do that for you, here is a link [link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay)

The methods is also called when the view first displays...

Comment: @implementation quartzViewController

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
 
 CGContextRef  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 24, kCGEncodingFontSpecific);
 CGContextSetTextPosition(context,80,80);
 CGContextShowText(context, "hello", 6);
 //not even this works
 CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 1,1, "hello", 6);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}


this is what I have done, but I am not actually getting why its happening, why its not called, ever if i am using setNeedsDisplay

Comment: you dont call it in view did load, call it else where, drawrect is called automatically when the view loads...are u sure u are adding your view correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Finally  I got the anser, just take a new class and inherit the class with UIView instead of NSobject,

This class will give us UIView object and it will also contain the drawRect method inbuilt.

so this is How i done. it :)